# Smart local copy of a remote directory

Tags: file-io, filesystems, rsync, nfs, sshfs

Currently I have a bunch of local copies of dev/production websites. Each copy contains the "files" directory, which contains files uploaded by site users. Currently I use `rsync` to synchronize the directories contents from remote servers (via `ssh`).

There are some annoyances:

1. I have to run `rsync` manually each time when I want fresh files (this could be automated of course, but as I have a lot of website copies, it's not a good idea).
2. The `rsync` execution takes some time.
3. Disc space on my laptop is running out.

I think all of this could be solved if there is some kind of a software that can work like a proxy:

1. When I list files, it requests the file list from the remote server and caches the results for some (configurable) time.
2. When I first time request file contents, it retrieves the remote file and saves it locally.
3. When I update a file, it only gets updated locally.
4. When I save a new file in the "files" directory, it not goes to the remote server.

Of course, the logic of such software should be much more complex, but I hope, my idea is clear: don't waste disk space, download files on demand, no remote changes.

Is there any software that works like that?

Comment: I just edited the question: files should not be changed on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Map a network drive with NFS or sshfs. Make local copies if you really need a file.

Comment: I don't know which files I need. When I work with a local website copy, the website engine retrieves some files from the "files" directory when it needs them. I can't predict which files it would need.

Answer (score 0):

I did not mention it in the question, but I needed this for work with Drupal. And now I have found a Drupal-only solution, the [Stage File Proxy](https://www.drupal.org/project/stage_file_proxy) module.

It does exactly what I need: downloads files from a remote server only when they are requested.